# How to define a geography column in a table with different columns type at SQL database

Tags: sql, geography, sqlgeography

Consider I have a table with different columns types:

```
CREATE TABLE [RentedHome]
(
     [HomeID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     [Address] CHAR (255) NOT NULL CHECK (LEN(Address) >= 2),
     [Landlord] CHAR (100) NOT NULL CHECK (LEN(Landlord) >= 2),
     [Tenant] CHAR (100) NOT NULL CHECK (LEN(Landlord) >= 2),
)
```

I want to add the `Geography` column to the mentioned table, how should I define the column (I want to insert just a geography-point for each home):

```
[Location] GEO (yyy)
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by most relational database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what concrete database system (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

Done!

```
CREATE TABLE [RentedHome]
(
      [HomeID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
      [Address] CHAR (255) NOT NULL CHECK (LEN(Address) >= 2),
      [Landlord] CHAR (100) NOT NULL CHECK (LEN(Landlord) >= 2),
      [GeoLocation] geography,
      [Tenant] CHAR (100) NOT NULL CHECK (LEN(Tenant) >= 2),
)
```

inserting example:

```
INSERT INTO [RentedHome] 
VALUES (1, '177 Huntington Ave #1010, Boston, MA 02115, United States', 'Northeastern University', geography::Point(42.34497193099456, -71.08252116132054, 4326), 'Network Lab')
```